# Parse QueryDict data

Tags: python, django, dictionary

Little new to django, I'm running python scrip to fetch the data and like to display in HTML table tags. Python script works and gather the data in the following:

```
[{'Device': 'device01', 'Port': 'ETH1/5', 'Provider': 'L3', 'ID': 1111, 'Remote': 'ISPCircuit', 'Destination Port': 'ISPPort'}, {'Device': 'device02', 'Port': 'ETH1/5', 'Provider': 'L3', 'ID': 2222, 'Remote': 'ISPCircuit', 'Destination Port': 'ISPPort'}]
```

When run the python script in Django in the view.py, I store the output in the following:

```py
if form.is_valid():
    ## Python script GatherData file
    output = gatherdata(location)
data = QueryDict(output, mutable=True)
## Dict format to fetch
context = {'location': location, 'data': data }
```

The reason of using `QueryDict`, was that the output from the python into the dict value as `data` adds the Strings for example:

```
{'location': 'DC1', 'data': b"[{'Device': ... '}]\n"}
```

unable to fetch data from the `data` 
Here is the output using QueryDict looks like the following:

```
<QueryDict: {"[{'Device': 'device01', 'Port': 'ETH1/5', 'Provider': 'L3', 'ID': 1111, 'Remote': 'ISPCircuit', 'Destination Port': 'ISPPort'}, {'Device': 'device02', 'Port': 'ETH1/5', 'Provider': 'L3', 'ID': 2222, 'Remote': 'ISPCircuit', 'Destination Port': 'ISPPort'}]\n": ['']}>
```

Explain above, How to parse the value from the given data, to html template

Given above, Thank for the ideas and suggestion.

I have tried, json.loads(output) but thru errors. I have tried `data = literal_eval(context['data'])` to remove the strings.

I have update the below suguesstion, in order to render via HTML, I have tired, this but don't get any data

```
      <tbody>
        {% for i in qd %}
            <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='/details/'>
              {% if i == "Device" %}
                {% for v in qd.i %}
                <td>{{ v }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
```

Comment: This is not a querydict, this looks like a Python object. You can use `ast.literal_eval()` here to unwrap it out of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the representation of a Python object. You can use `ast.literal_eval(..)` to convert it to its Python equivalent, and then update the `QueryDict` by iterating over the list. Like:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from django.http import QueryDict

response = "[{'Device': 'device01', 'Port': 'ETH1/5', 'Provider': 'L3', 'ID': 1111, 'Remote': 'ISPCircuit', 'Destination Port': 'ISPPort'}, {'Device': 'device02', 'Port': 'ETH1/5', 'Provider': 'L3', 'ID': 2222, 'Remote': 'ISPCircuit', 'Destination Port': 'ISPPort'}]"
data = literal_eval(response)
qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
for item in data:
    qd.update(item)
```

if `response` is a `bytes`, then you can first decode it to a string:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from django.http import QueryDict

response = b"[{'Device': 'device01', 'Port': 'ETH1/5', 'Provider': 'L3', 'ID': 1111, 'Remote': 'ISPCircuit', 'Destination Port': 'ISPPort'}, {'Device': 'device02', 'Port': 'ETH1/5', 'Provider': 'L3', 'ID': 2222, 'Remote': 'ISPCircuit', 'Destination Port': 'ISPPort'}]"
response = response.decode()
data = literal_eval(response)
qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
for item in data:
    qd.update(item)
```

At the end, we get the following `QueryDict`:

```
>>> qd
<QueryDict: {'Device': ['device01', 'device02'], 'Port': ['ETH1/5', 'ETH1/5'], 'Provider': ['L3', 'L3'], 'ID': [1111, 2222], 'Remote': ['ISPCircuit', 'ISPCircuit'], 'Destination Port': ['ISPPort', 'ISPPort']}>
```

But you probably do *not* want to convert this to a `QueryDict` anyway. This is just a *list* of dictionaries. Each dictionary contans a `'Device'`, `'Port'`, `Provider'` and `ID` key. So you might want to just process the dictionaries with a `for` loop.

Comment: Hi, thank you @willem for the suggestion, but got error from the response:

`ValueError: malformed node or string: b"[{'Device': .... }]\n"`

Comment: @miu: you will first need to decode the bytestring with `response = response.decode()` for example.

Comment: Hi, @willem, that works thank you, It seems I was getting `b` as bytes value.
To send fetch each value from the `Device` I would need for loops within for loop to fetch values?

Comment: I have tried following in HTML is this correct:
```<tbody>
        {% for i in qd %}
            <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='/details/'>
              {% if i == "Device" %}
                {% for v in qd.i %}
                <td>{{ v }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fetch the data and able to display via html rendering. Didn't have to use the `qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)` just used `response = response.decode()` to solve the problem. As far as the html, was able to use FOR LOOP `.items()` to fetch the data. Thank you all for the input.